# ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot convert the JSON string because a dictionary that was converted from the string contains the duplicated keys

Tags: json, rest, powershell

The following JSON is getting returned from OData API service:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x0100BC97B2F575CB0C42B79549F3BABD32A8",
        "Title": "Nokia California",
        "Address": "200 South Matilda Avenue\nW Washington Ave\n94086 Sunnyvale, California\nUnited States of America",
        "ID": 1,
        "Modified": "2014-02-24T10:06:39Z",
        "Created": "2014-02-24T10:06:39Z",
        "AuthorId": 12,
        "EditorId": 12,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "d12aafad-502a-4968-a69e-36a7ea05ec80"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and saved as a string into variable named `$data`

An attempt to convert a JSON-formatted string to a custom object using [ConvertFrom-Json](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx) cmdlet:

```
$results = $data | ConvertFrom-Json
```

gives the following error:

> ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot convert the JSON string because a dictionary
>   that was converted from the string contains the  duplicated keys 'Id'
>   and 'ID'.

Is there any way to convert the specified JSON-formatted string in PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell V1.0, or in PowerShell V2.0 when the JSON is too big,  I still use a convertion to XML :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.ServiceModel.Web, System.Runtime.Serialization
function Convert-JsonToXml
{
  PARAM([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$json)

  BEGIN
  { 
    $mStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream 
  }

  PROCESS
  {
    $json | Write-String -stream $mStream
  }

  END
  {
    $mStream.Position = 0
    try
    {
       $jsonReader = [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory]::CreateJsonReader($mStream,[System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas]::Max)
       $xml = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
       $xml.Load($jsonReader)
       $xml
    }
    finally
    {
       $jsonReader.Close()
       $mStream.Dispose()
    }
  }
}
```

Using this code you can loop thru your items you can test :

```
$a = Get-Content C:\temp\jsontest.txt
$b.root.d.results.Item
$b.root.d.results.Item[7].Id[0].InnerText
```

---

(Edited)

In you case I would only replace the expected duplicate ID/Id

```
$data = Get-Content C:\temp\jsontest.txt -Raw
$datacorrected = $a -creplace '"Id":','"Id-minus":'
$psJsonIn = $datacorrected | ConvertFrom-Json
```

If really you've got unexpected duplicate you can write a function that trap the convertion error due to duplicated key and replace one.

Comment: @Vadim Gremyachev, I edit my answer with a second turn arround (not really better).

Answer (score 16):

This is how I have done with it:

```
$results = $data.ToString().Replace("ID", "_ID") | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: I like this better, but I would recommend this minor modification:  $results = $data.ToString().Replace("""ID""", "_ID") | ConvertFrom-Json  which will target just "ID" (as it would appear in the property name, if that is the whole property name) but avoid modifying any other attributes selected where "ID"  appears as only a part of the name. E.,g., avoid changing "FLUID_VOLUME" to "FLU_ID_VOLUME".

Answer (score 4):

**Note, both examples assume the JSON is stored in the `$jsonstring` variable.**

In **PowerShell Core**, **[`ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.2#example-4-convert-a-json-string-to-a-hash-table)** is the easiest alternative:

```bash
$json = $jsonstring | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
$json['d']['results']

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Modified                       2/24/2014 10:06:39 AM
Title                          Nokia California
Attachments                    False
ID                             1
ContentTypeId                  0x0100BC97B2F575CB0C42B79549F3BABD32A8
GUID                           d12aafad-502a-4968-a69e-36a7ea05ec80
Created                        2/24/2014 10:06:39 AM
EditorId                       12
AuthorId                       12
Address                        200 South Matilda Avenue…
Id                             1
OData__UIVersionString         1.0
FileSystemObjectType           0
```

In **Windows PowerShell**, you can use the **[`Deserialize(String, Type)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8#system-web-script-serialization-javascriptserializer-deserialize(system-string-system-type))** from the **[`JavaScriptSerializer` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8)**.

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions

$serializer = [Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]::new()
$json = $serializer.Deserialize($jsonstring, [hashtable])
$json['d']['results']
```

Answer (score 3):

ConvertFrom-JSON it going to try to create a PS Custom Object from the JSON string.  PowerShell object property names are case-insensitive, so "ID" and "id" represent the same property name.  You're going to have to do something with those duplicate property names in your JSON before you try to do that conversion, or it's going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I used the ToLower() before converting the json to object, resolved my issue.

```
$sdf = $data.ToLower() | ConvertFrom-Json
```