# Compare two JSON objects in windows PowerShell produced by PowerShell and Python

Tags: python, json, powershell

I'm attempting to port .Net PowerShell code over to Python. In order to ensure that the python code is correct I'm testing the PowerShell output vs the Python output.

In powershell I have

```
$ps_output = PowerShell-Function $log_path
$python_output = Python-Function $log_path
($ps_output -eq $python_output)
```

and if I run compare-object I get

```
InputObject                                                                                                 SideIndicator                                                                                              
-----------                                                                                                 -------------                                                                                              
The Python Win32 extensions for NT (service, event logging) appear not to be available.                     =>                                                                                                         
[{'blocks': '5860533168', 'sn': 'PN2234J4T5DR', 'fw': 'MF8OAC0', 'device': 'da1', 'data': ['@{n... =>                                                                                                         
[{"bay":"1","device":"da1","make":"HGST","type":"HUS724030ALA640","fw":"MF8OAC0","sn":"PN2234J4T5DR",... <=
```

I'm reasonably sure that the reason the equality check is failing is because the ordering of the key value pairs is different from python to PowerShell.

So I'm looking for a way to test equality between json objects in powershell or a means to order my python produced json in a way that matches the powershell output.

I've tried using an OrderedDict. This has the two fold problem of putting

```
[OrderedDict{...
```

in front of the string and also makes the code pretty brittle (since I'll have a dependency on when something is added to a dictionary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you try to first convert to a PowerShell Object using `ConvertFrom-Json` and then use `Compare-Object` ?

```
$ps_output = PowerShell-Function $log_path
$python_output = Python-Function $log_path
$po_ps_output = $ps_output | ConvertFrom-Json
$po_python_output = $python_output | ConvertFrom-Json
Compare-Object $po_ps_output $po_python_output
```

Comment: So I've run into a major flaw with ConvertFrom-Json. It doesn't work if the JSON is larger than 1MB.

Comment: Don't you have a trouble with the depth see [Convertto-Json](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17972159/608772) (The same to ConvertFrom-Json).Perhaps you can convert JSON to XML have a look to [Convert-JsonToXml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22131452/608772)

Comment: Ahhh, derp. that fixes the depth issue but my python didn't produce proper json. I'll make this answer as correct after I have the code actually working.