# JSON array to hashtable conversion throwing "Cannot index in to a null array"

Tags: powershell

I have the below JSON file

```
{
  "rel": "true",
  "ref": "true",
  "jfro": "arem",
  "app": [
    {
      "appkey": "mule",
      "build": "maven"     
    },
    {
      "appkey": "npm",
      "build": "dotnet"     
    }
  ]
}
```

I have my script to conver the json to hashtable

```
 $json_path =  Get-ChildItem "test.json" -recurse  | %{$_.FullName}
 $json = Get-Content  $json_path -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.psobject.properties | ForEach {
  $hashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value  }
```

And its throwing , the exact same script and same file works on a different machine which also has powershell 5.1

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:5 char:3
+   $hashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value  }
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: which `$hashtable` ? also, why ? pwsh 7+ has `-AsHashtable` and pwsh 5.1 can use JavaScriptSerializer without a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72745321/15339544

Comment: You never define variable `$hashtable`

Comment: Thats correct, i didnt define even on other machine but it worked there, but after i defined its working fine now Thank you