# Powershell: Extracting values from multiple json objects

Tags: powershell

I am trying to extract the value from multiple json objects in powershell. I was reading up on using `Where-Object` for this.

I have the following:

....

```
foreach($item in $table)
{

   $result = $item.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Key -in ('Manufacturer')}
   Write-Host $result.Value
}
```

where $item holds multiple json objects i.e.

```
{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "GMC", "Color": "Red"}
{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Ford", "Color": "White"}
{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Nissan", "Color": "Black"}
{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Rolls Royce", "Color": "White"}
{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Lincoln", "Color": "Purple"}
{"Manufacturer": "BMW", "Color": "White", "Type": "Car"}
{"Manufacturer": "GMC", "Type": "Car", "Color": "Red"}
{"Type": "Car", "Color": "White", "Manufacturer": "Ford"}
{"Type": "Car", "Color": "Black", "Manufacturer": "Nissan"}
```

When I execute this script nothing is displayed, its just blank.

I tried one json object in a separate terminal and did `$result = $item.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Key -in ('Manufacturer')} Write-Host $result.Value` and it returned GMC.

Can I not extract only Manufacturer the way I am doing it in `$result` for multiple json objects?

Comment: Would be helpful if you provide a full sample of your Json, also `$_.Key` would be valid only if you are using `-AsHashtable` with `ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: Please see updated post. Forgot to mention that `Table` is `ConvertFrom-Json` @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems to be valid assuming your Json is an array of objects like the ones you're showing. Likely you're just missing [`-AsHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-convert-a-json-string-to-a-hash-table). You can also use `-eq` instead of `-in` (this operator is for containment, though would also work in this case).

```bash
$json = '[
    {"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "GMC", "Color": "Red"},
    {"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Ford", "Color": "White"},
    {"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Nissan", "Color": "Black"}
]' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

$json | ForEach-Object {
    $_.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object Key -EQ 'Manufacturer'
}
```

If you want to extract the value from each key / value pair, you can use:

```bash
$json | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.ContainsKey('Manufacturer')) {
        $_['Manufacturer']
    }
}

# Outputs:
GMC
Ford
Nissan
```

**NOTE:** `-AsHashtable` parameter is introduced in PowerShell 6, for PowerShell 5.1, you can use:

```bash
$json = '[
    {"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "GMC", "Color": "Red"},
    {"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Ford", "Color": "White"},
    {"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Nissan", "Color": "Black"}
]' | ConvertFrom-Json

$json | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Manufacturer) {
        $_.Manufacturer
    }
}
```

Or, even simpler, you can use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2), downside is, if there are objects that do not have a `.Manufacturer` property you would end up with `$null` values in your collection.

```bash
$json.Manufacturer

# Outputs:
GMC
Ford
Nissan
```

---

**EDIT:** From feedback provided in comments, it seems what OP has is actually an array of strings where each string is Json object, something like this:

```bash
$table = @(
    '{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "GMC", "Color": "Red"}'
    '{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Ford", "Color": "White"}'
    '{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Nissan", "Color": "Black"}'
    '{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Rolls Royce", "Color": "White"}'
    '{"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "Lincoln", "Color": "Purple"}'
    '{"Manufacturer": "BMW", "Color": "White", "Type": "Car"}'
    '{"Manufacturer": "GMC", "Type": "Car", "Color": "Red"}'
    '{"Type": "Car", "Color": "White", "Manufacturer": "Ford"}'
    '{"Type": "Car", "Color": "Black", "Manufacturer": "Nissan"}'
)
```

In which case, the solution would be to parse each Json string to extract the value from the `.Manufacturer` property:

```bash
foreach ($item in $table) {
    # this assumes each string will have a `.Manufacturer` property
    # if you're not sure if that will be the case you should add an `if` condition
    # as shown in previous examples
    (ConvertFrom-Json $item).Manufacturer
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Whenever I do `-AsHashTable` it tells me `ConvertFrom-Json : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name AsHashtable`. Even if I just copy your @json and paste it in my terminal it says that.

Comment: @MarkCo see the update

Comment: Is there a way to create the hash table without using the parameter -AsHashtable?

Comment: @MarkCo assuming you're in powershell 5.1, yeah you can use the `JavaScriptSerializer` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080350/convertfrom-json-cannot-convert-the-json-string-because-a-dictionary-that-was/72745321#72745321

Comment: Thank you! So just realized that `$json` is an array of objects. In my case, it is not an array of objects. `$json` just holds the objects shown in the post. In this case, what would be the approach for this situation?

Comment: @MarkCo so `$item` is a single string containing a json object? can you do `$table | Get-Member` and check what type you get

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, exactly it is a single string containing multiple json objects. I get `string ToString() string S = {"Type": "Car", "Manufacturer": "GMC", "Color": "Red"}`

Comment: @MarkCo see the edit, hopefully that helps

Comment: Perfect, this helped! Many thanks! @SantiagoSquarzon